# BETWEEN is not behaving in an inclusive manner

Tags: sql, postgresql, between

I have a query that returns data from a table based on user id and two dates. The dates all look like this:
`2018-10-07T00:00:00.000Z`
`2018-10-06T00:00:00.000Z`
...and so on.

Most of the time the query will provide a date range, like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM "some_table" WHERE (user_id = 3 AND TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-05') ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
```

But occasionally users might specify a single day, in which case the query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "some_table" WHERE (user_id = 3 AND TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2018-10-05' AND '2018-10-05') ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
```

It is my understanding that `BETWEEN` is supposed to be inclusive... can anyone help me understand why its returning no data?

Comment: it **is** inclusive, but your range of dates goes from `20181005 00:00:00.00` to `20181005 00:00:00.00`...soooo

Comment: It will correctly include all records having timestamp = 2018-10-05 00:00:00.0000000000000000 but not anything 1 nanosecond after it.

Comment: Assuming that you are checking only on date and not datetime, you can cast TIMESTAMP to date and use that for comparison -- TIMESTAMP::date BETWEEN '2018-10-05' AND '2018-10-05'

Comment: `2018-10-06T00:00:00.000` is not a "date" - it's a timestamp and thus the _time_ is part of the comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timestamp `'2018-10-05'` is understood to be `2018-10-05T00:00:00.000Z`, so your range is from `2018-10-05T00:00:00.000Z` to `2018-10-05T00:00:00.000Z`, only one millisecond. Include the hours, minutes, and seconds in your query, or increment the end date by one day when both the begin date and end date are the same day.

To avoid the problem a little more reliably, you might consider not using `BETWEEN` with dates at all. Use something like `TIMESTAMP >= '2018-10-05' AND TIMESTAMP < '2018-10-06'` instead.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize it was automatically assuming seconds.

Comment: `BETWEEN` can be tricky sometimes, using `<= and >` can help if your doing the same day like you have in your example.

Comment: `BETWEEN` with `DATE` values is not "tricky" at all. The only thing where it get's "tricky" is when using timestamps with `between` -  or worse, when **mixing** timestamp and date values. If only the date is relevant one could also use `where "timestamp"::date between date '2018-10-01' and date '2018-10-05'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - thanks for the reminder. I've converted my date to a timestamp before the query is made.